# write to a csv file

Tags: php, fputcsv

getHistory downloads a CSV file from Yahoo finance API, i am trying to get the CSV file, and insert the symbol infront of each of the entries in the file. After that is done i want to write the CSV file back to $symbol.csv. My data is the way i want it, i just cant seem to write it to a CSV file. What am i doing wrong? Or is there a better way to go about this?

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen(getHistory("T","2010-06-1"), "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if($row = 1){array_unshift($data,"Symbol"); }
        else  { array_unshift($data, "T"); }
        $fp = fopen('t.csv', 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);
        $row++;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Place the `$fp = fopen('t.csv', 'w');` before your loop, and the `fclose($fp);` after it.  You don't need to open/close the file on *each* iteration.

Comment: Also, use `==` or `===` for comparison.  `if($row === 1)`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. And i knew about using ==  i just slipped up on that. but moving the fopen didnt even occur to me

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you are opening and closing the file on *each* iteration.  You should open the csv file before the loop, add to it, then close it when the loop is done.

Also, you should use `===` or `==` for comparisons.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen(getHistory("T","2010-06-1"), "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // This truncates the file to zero length
    // so, we only need to do this once, before the loop
    $fp = fopen('t.csv', 'w');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if($row === 1){array_unshift($data,"Symbol"); }
        else  { array_unshift($data, "T"); }
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
        $row++;
    }
    // Close it once we're all done
    fclose($fp);
}
fclose($handle);
```